# Golang query with float value is not working correctly

Tags: go

I am doing a Golang query to the postgres database and the weird thing is that the query only works if I hard-code the value in for instance this query works

```
db.QueryRow("select json_build_object('Streams', array_to_json(array_agg(t))) from (select p.name FROM profiles as p INNER JOIN streams as s ON(s.profile_id = 
p.id) WHERE s.latitudes >=28.1036 AND shared = false order by id desc limit 15)t").Scan(&result)
```

The only part that I now change is where the **WHERE s.latitudes >=28.1036**
instead of having that value hard-coded I Past it through a form and now have the query like this

```
   db.QueryRow("select json_build_object('Streams', array_to_json(array_agg(t))) from (select p.name FROM profiles as p INNER JOIN streams as s ON(s.profile_id = 
    p.id) WHERE s.latitudes>=$1 AND shared = false order by id desc limit 15)t",LatMin).Scan(&result)
```

Now the query just comes back null and I do know for a fact that the LatMin variable is being populated correctly as this is my code

```
    func Auto_Location(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {

        var result string
        if r.Method == "GET" {

        } else {
            r.ParseForm() }

        LatMin := r.Form["LatMin"]

    db,err := sql.Open("Postgres Connects")
    if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
    println(err)

    }
   db.QueryRow("select json_build_object('Streams', array_to_json(array_agg(t))) from (select p.name FROM profiles as p INNER JOIN streams as s ON(s.profile_id = 
        p.id) WHERE s.latitudes>=$1 AND shared = false order by id desc limit 15)t",LatMin).Scan(&result)
    defer db.Close()


    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")


    fmt.Fprintf(w,result)
        fmt.Println("Value:", LatMin)

    }
```

Again as you can see from the code I am using FMT and the LatMin has the correct value of 28.1036 is there something that I am missing here.. The postgres package I am using is    **_ "github.com/lib/pq"** . I am thinking it is an issue with float values because if I change LatMin to 28 it works but 28.1036 does not

Comment: Have you tried printing out the two query strings and checking for differences?

Comment: Yes I did and finally found the answer

Answer (score 0):

Hello everyone I have found the answer, if you are collecting form information on a Post and if some of the values are of type decimal,float or double and you want to query that value into the database then use

```
r.FormValue("LatMin")
```

instead of

```
r.Form["LatMin"]
```

as that will get the correcte

Both of those methods get the correct value however Form[""] as issues with the database.